# Summernote Code is over writing everything in Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I am trying to add Media (Images/Videos) to Summernote Rich Text Editor. From outside the Summernote default Options.

I am succeeded to add Plain Text but When I add Media it appears to remove everything written in Summernote Editor and Over-write Media.

**Code**

```
$("#addImages").click(function () {
            $('#summernote').summernote('editor.saveRange');
            $('#summernote').summernote('editor.restoreRange');
            $('#summernote').summernote('editor.focus');
            $('#summernote').summernote('editor.code', '<p><img src="img/angular_logo.png" /></p>');
        });
```

Above code isn't working

**Working but Over-writing Content**

```
$("#addImages").click(function () {
            $('#summernote').summernote('editor.saveRange');
            $('#summernote').summernote('editor.restoreRange');
            $('#summernote').summernote('editor.focus');
            $('#summernote').summernote('code', '<p><img src="img/angular_logo.png" /></p>');
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for.

**Change**

```
$('#summernote').summernote('code', '<p><img src="img/angular_logo.png" /></p>');
```

**To**

```
$('#summernote').summernote('editor.pasteHTML', '<img src="image_path.jpg" />');
```

Comment: glad you got what you were looking for